# connent C++ to Matlab for plotting

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to connect C++(32bitVS) to Matlab(64bit) in my laptop. I have already added the path under the VC++ directions and I have also activated the platform to x64.
I have also added "libeng.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib" under linker>>input>>additional dependencies.

However, I have still the error: **the program can't start because libeng.dll is missing from your computer**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS should be able to find libeng.dll when running your program.

Either add `libeng.dll`'s containing folder to the `PATH` environment variable, or as a hack, you can copy `libeng.dll` to next to the executable (the program you are running).

Comment: I have added the folder which contains libeng.dll to the executable directories and it doesn't work

Comment: @gugabrielle As the answer said, add the directory to the PATH environment variable OR copy libeng.dll to the directory, where your exe is.